# Is is possible to enable "Hard reload" and "Empty cache and hard reload" options without having devtool open?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools, browser-cache, reload

I would like to know if there is an option or a switch to enable the "Hard reload" and "Empty cache and hard reload" options under the reload button without having to open devtools, so that they always pop up, even if the devtools are not open.

I know about the shorcut keys, but if only it was possible to still have all the options available regardless of the devtools, that would be nice.

Comment: Devtools options definitely can't pop up without devtools being open.

Comment: Agree this would be a nice option

Answer (score 0):

I was just googling this and couldn't find anything that would enable the hard reload feature but here's what I do:

1. ctrl + F5 (if it doesn't work then do number 2)
2. ctrl + shift + delete ( only check cached images and filed) and hit F5 again

Answer (score 0):

## <**Google Chrome**>

Reload the page by emptying cache:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Reload the page by not emptying cache:

<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>